# help with view rendering asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

My app has these models:

patient, which has one patient_info, which has one history and has many exams.... I want to create a Report view where I show all this data.. right now Im creating the view and its turning out to be ugly and long.. is there a way I could create separate views for each of this things and then just render them in one Report View?

Comment: Which ASP.NET MVC version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could break up the report into partial views and render them using Htm.RenderPartial

Answer (score 1):

You could create a controller action for some of the sections and grab that data via AJAX when needed.  You could use an expander type control to determine what is shown and grab the data only when a section gets expanded.  This would also allow the possibility of displaying the patient info while loading the history using AJAX so the page loads fast.